# How to make this rewrite rule work?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I'm trying to do is a pretty simple idea but somehow it doesn't work. I need this rewrite rule to work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9-=]*)$ index.php?op=$1&$2 [L,NC]
```

I think it's pretty much self explanatory but I want the rule to pass the first regex group as the `op` parameter and the the second regex group is passed untouched to the script. Like this:

> http://example.org/view/?post_slug=awesome-apache-mods -->
>   http://example.org/index.php?op=view&post_slug=awesome-apache-mods

The problem here is that the first part works just fine, meaning the `op` parameter is set correctly but the second part gets lost. I mean literaly lost. When I issue `print_r($_GET)` there is just the `op` parameter.

```
Array
(
    [op] => view
)
```

I wonder what's wrong here?

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9-=]*)$ index.php?op=$1&post_slug=$2 [L,NC] Smome thing like that perhaps? You missed the second variable and since it's null vaule variable sent which dont show up in print_R

Comment: I cant see any (under score _) in the regex for matching post_slug?

Comment: @IesusSonesson The second var is not always `post_slug`. The point is it can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your pattern using preg_match_all its not matching the URL because _ is not defined in the pattern, but when I added _ it matched the URL:

```
$text = 'view/?post_slug=awesome-apache-mods';
$pattern = '/^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/\?([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]*)$/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $out);
print_r($out);
```

Then your .htaccess pattern should be like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/\?([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]*)$ [L,NC, QSA]
```

Its better to use this if /view is constant:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-=]*)$ index.php?op=view&$2 [L,NC, QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it when I get back home and let you know if it worked or not. Though I don't think the problem is with the missing underscore because I have tried it before. It seems that it might be the unescaped question mark!